# php resize image without loss quality

Tags: php, image, php-gd

i've implement this method (by following php tutorial) for create preview of an images:

```
function createPreview($image_path, $filename) {

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(350, 350);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_path);

    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($thumb, $filename."_prev.jpg");
}
```

but i've noticed that scaled image loss a lot of quality. How can i preserve quality of scaled image (i can't use imagick, my server doesn't support it)

Comment: use `imagejpeg($thumb, $filename."_prev.jpg", 100);`

Comment: quality is still too low

Comment: Step two: use [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)

Comment: ok got it. make it as an answer, so i'll accept it. thank you

Comment: It's hard getting around the image processing quality of GD. The only real option I know of is to use imagick if you want good results.

Comment: @giozh, share the full code, where the compressed image will be stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) uses 75 quality by default. So you need to define it explicitly.

```
imagejpeg($thumb, $filename."_prev.jpg", 100);
```

Also, use [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

> imagecopyresampled() copies a rectangular portion of one image to
>   another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in
>   particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal
>   of clarity.

Answer (score 7):

Use `imagecopyresampled` instead of `imagecopyresized` (it's the same arguments so just change the function) :)

Comment: Thanks, great suggest!

Answer (score -2):

Below the PHP code that resize the image without losing the quality as well as the resized image will fit into the mentioned resize width and height as per the aspect ratio.

The code that reads the image from one folder(img) and resized the same image to desired width and height to another mentioned folder(resizedImage).

Hope it will help.

Thanks

```
<?php
function resizeImage($SrcImage,$DestImage, $thumb_width,$thumb_height,$Quality)
{
    list($width,$height,$type) = getimagesize($SrcImage);
    switch(strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type($type)))
    {
        case 'image/gif':
            $NewImage = imagecreatefromgif($SrcImage);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $NewImage = imagecreatefrompng($SrcImage);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $NewImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($SrcImage);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
    $original_aspect = $width / $height;
    $positionwidth = 0;
    $positionheight = 0;
    if($original_aspect > 1)    {
        $new_width = $thumb_width;
        $new_height = $new_width/$original_aspect;
        while($new_height > $thumb_height) {
            $new_height = $new_height - 0.001111;
            $new_width  = $new_height * $original_aspect;
            while($new_width > $thumb_width) {
                $new_width = $new_width - 0.001111;
                $new_height = $new_width/$original_aspect;
            }

        }
    } else {
        $new_height = $thumb_height;
        $new_width = $new_height/$original_aspect;
        while($new_width > $thumb_width) {
            $new_width = $new_width - 0.001111;
            $new_height = $new_width/$original_aspect;
            while($new_height > $thumb_height) {
                $new_height = $new_height - 0.001111;
                $new_width  = $new_height * $original_aspect;
            }
        }
    }
    if($width < $new_width && $height < $new_height){
        $new_width = $width;
        $new_height = $height;
        $positionwidth = ($thumb_width - $new_width) / 2;
        $positionheight = ($thumb_height - $new_height) / 2;
    }elseif($width < $new_width && $height > $new_height){
        $new_width = $width;
        $positionwidth = ($thumb_width - $new_width) / 2;
        $positionheight = 0;
    }elseif($width > $new_width && $height < $new_height){
        $new_height = $height;
        $positionwidth = 0;
        $positionheight = ($thumb_height - $new_height) / 2;
    } elseif($width > $new_width && $height > $new_height){
        if($new_width < $thumb_width) {
            $positionwidth = ($thumb_width - $new_width) / 2;
        } elseif($new_height < $thumb_height) {
            $positionheight = ($thumb_height - $new_height) / 2;
        }
    }
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
    /********************* FOR WHITE BACKGROUND  *************************/
        //$white = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255,255,255);
        //imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $white);
    if(imagecopyresampled($thumb, $NewImage,$positionwidth, $positionheight,0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height)) {
        if(imagejpeg($thumb,$DestImage,$Quality)) {
            imagedestroy($thumb);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function resize($source,$destination,$newWidth,$newHeight)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    $ImagesDirectory = $source;
    $DestImagesDirectory = $destination;
    $NewImageWidth = $newWidth;
    $NewImageHeight = $newHeight;
    $Quality = 100;
    $imagePath = $ImagesDirectory;
    $destPath = $DestImagesDirectory;
    $checkValidImage = getimagesize($imagePath);
    if(file_exists($imagePath) && $checkValidImage)
    {
        if(resizeImage($imagePath,$destPath,$NewImageWidth,$NewImageHeight,$Quality))
            echo " --> ".$source.'  --> Resize Successful!<BR><BR>';
        else
            echo " --> ".$source.'  --> Resize Failed!<BR><BR>';
    }
}
function getDirContents($filter = '', &$results = array()) {
    // Source FOLDER
    $files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imageresize/img/');
    $fileCount = 1;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $ext = explode(".",$value);
        $fname = $ext[0].round(microtime(true)*1000);
        $filename = $fname.".".$ext[1];
        // Source PATH
        $path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imageresize/img/'.$value); 

        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            if(empty($filter) || preg_match($filter, $path)){ 
                echo "Image # ".$fileCount;
                $results[] = $path;
                // Destination PATH
                $destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imageresize/resizedImage/'.$value;

                // Change the desired "WIDTH" and "HEIGHT"
                $newWidth = 400; // Desired WIDTH
                $newHeight = 350; // Desired HEIGHT

                resize($path,$destination,$newWidth,$newHeight);
                $fileCount++;
            }
        } elseif($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getDirContents($path, $filter, $results);
        }
    }
    return $results;
} 
getDirContents();
exit;
?>
```